# Creation of JavaRDD object has failed

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have this piece of code:

```
ArrayList<Row> list = new ArrayList<Row>();
Row testRow = RowFactory.create(true, 101.0, "string");
list.add(testRow);
JavaRDD<Row> testRDD = JavaSparkContext.parallelize(list);
```

In the last line of this code I have the following error message:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
>   prallelize(List < Row > ) from the type JavaSparkContext.

How can I improve my code and create a JavaRDD object from my list (which actually should have multiple Rows objects). Currently I don't understand which part of my code is static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to instantiate JavaSparkContext.

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
conf.setAppName("YOUR APP");
//other config like conf.setMaster("YOUR MASTER");
JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

//and then
JavaRDD<Row> testRDD = ctx.parallelize(list);
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work. I already created conf object at the top of my code, I just didn't create the JavaSparkContext object. Thanks.