# SparkSession and SparkContext initiation in PySpark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I would like to know the PySpark equivalent of the following code in Scala. I am using databricks. I need the same output as below:-

**to create new Spark session and output the session id (SparkSession@123d0e8)**

```
val new_spark = spark.newSession()

**Output** 
new_spark: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@123d0e8
```

**to view SparkContext and output the SparkContext id (SparkContext@2dsdas33)**

```
new_spark.sparkContext
**Output** 
org.apache.spark.SparkContext = org.apache.spark.SparkContext@2dsdas33
```

Comment: Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39780792/how-to-build-a-sparksession-in-spark-2-0-using-pyspark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very similar. If you have already a session and want to open another one, you can use

```
my_session = spark.newSession()

print(my_session)
```

This will produce the new session object I think you are trying to create

```
<pyspark.sql.session.SparkSession object at 0x7fc3bae3f550>
```

`spark` is a session object already running, because you are using a databricks notebook

Comment: thanks this worked! how can I print sparkContext in PySpark?

Comment: You can run `print(my_session.sparkContext)`

Answer (score 0):

SparkSession could be created as http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
>>> from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
>>> SparkSession.builder.config(conf=SparkConf())
```

or

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
>>> spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('FirstSparkApp').getOrCreate()
```