# How to migrate Spark application with multiple SparkContexts active?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am migrating from Spark 1.3.0 to Spark 2.1.1. 
Earlier I was able to create SparkContext on spark 1.3.0  in Java using the following:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(dsp.getAppName()).setMaster("local").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");
JavaSparkContext java_sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
```

However I get error "Multiple running SparkContexts detected in the same JVM!" and " `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_0_piece0 of broadcast_0"`

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the javadoc of [JavaSparkContext](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext.html):

> Only one SparkContext may be active per JVM. You must stop() the active SparkContext before creating a new one.

In Scala there's [SparkContext.getOrCreate](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext$) that you can use from any place in a Spark application to get or instantiate a `SparkContext` and register it as a singleton object.

> **getOrCreate(): SparkContext** This function may be used to get or instantiate a SparkContext and register it as a singleton object. Because we can only have one active SparkContext per JVM, this is useful when applications may wish to share a SparkContext.

I can't find Java's version of the method so perhaps just use Scala's.

Comment: @Ankur100 Please accept the answer if it worked for you. I and the community would appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Jacek. I have posted the solution to my problem as that solution worked in my case.
I will try your method too if I run into problem in future.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer seemed to work in my case:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34880317/3567232

All I did was to create a new JavaSparkContext from already existing SparkContext.

Comment: yes. I think I didn't need multiple SparkContext. However if someone want to use multiple contexts, they will find your answer more helpful